# Is the set of invertible operators on a normed space open?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am aware that if $X$ is a Banach space then the set of invertible operators is open in $L(X,X)$ where we use the notation $L(X,X)$ for the space of all linear bounded maps from $X$ to itself.

Does the result still hold if $X$ is just a normed space?

Is there any "easy" counterexample?

Comment: related for the Banach algebra case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613552/173147

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subspace $X$ of $\ell^2$ which is just the span of the orthonormal basis. Let $S\colon \ell^2\to \ell^2$ be defined by $S(e_n)=e_{n+1}$. Then $(1-\varepsilon S)^{-1}=1+\sum_{n\geq 1} (\varepsilon\cdot S)^n$ for $\varepsilon$ smaller than $1$.

Now notice that $1-0\cdot S$ restricted to $X$ is invertible, by no restriction of an $(1-\varepsilon \cdot S)$ is, for $\varepsilon\neq 0$, because $(1-\varepsilon S)^{-1}$ do not preserve $X$. You need a small argument to show that the restriction cannot have an inverse different from the restriction of the inverse in $\ell^2$, but that follows from denseness and uniqueness of inverses in $B(\ell^2)$.

(Alternatively, you can see that $(1-\varepsilon S)$ is not onto, as @SheldonAxler suggested in a deleted answer.)

Comment: I do not clearly understand what is the subspace $X$. Don't the orthonormal elements $\{e_i\}$ span the whole of $l^2$?

Comment: @user146846: No. They span a dense subspace.

Comment: We are talking about (Hamael) basis then?
Also, could you please explain what do you mean by $(1- \varepsilon S)^{-1}$ does not preserve $X$.

Comment: No, we are talking about the standard orthonormal basis. Hamel basis would be far from countable, and in that case, the span would be the entire $\ell^2$... I mean that $(1-\varepsilon S)^{-1}[X]\not\subseteq X$.