# Prove that the set of invertible elements in a Banach algebra is open

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, inverse, banach-algebras

I am reading Banach algebras. There is a question in the text that show that set of all invertible elements is an open set.

I have thought a lot about it, considering it as a normed space but am not exactly sure how to show that it has an open ball around any invertible element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to explain step by step, because I studied the subject, here what I wrote at the time

**Definition:** Let $A$ be  Banach algebra and G(A) the set of it's invertible elements.

**Theorem:**
 If $x$ is invertible, $h \in A$ and $|h| < \frac{1}{2||x^{-1}||}$.  Then,

$x+h \in G(A)$

**Proof:**
We have  $||x^{-1}h|| \leq ||x^{-1}|| \;||h|| < \frac{1}{2}<1$. So, $1_A +x^{-1}h$ is invertible by the series
$$(1_A +x^{-1}h)^{-1} =\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} (-x^{-1}h)^k, $$
which converges because $||x^{-1}h||<1.$ So,
$$x+h=x(1_A+x^{-1}h) $$ is invertible,
because it's the product of two invertible elements, $x$ and $(1_A+x^{-1}h).$

**Theorem:** 
For every Banach algebra $A$, $G(A)$ is a open subset of $A$

**Proof:**

$G(A)$ is open, because given $x \in G(A)$, we have
 $$B(x, \frac{1}{2||x^{-1}||}) \subset G(A). $$
 it follows from
 $$ B(x, \frac{1}{2||x^{-1}||}) =\{ y \in A\;|\; ||y-x||\leq \frac{1}{2||x^{-1}||}  \}$$
 we take $h=y-x,$ so $y=x+h$. By the last theorem we have $x+h \in G(A)$, given $x \in A$ and $||h|| \leq \frac{1}{2||x^{-1}||}. $

Comment: Very nice @RenjiRodrigo

Comment: Do you need the factor of $\frac12$?

Comment: Not really @mr_e_man, any <1 constant is sufficient.

Comment: @prikarsartam - I think you don't need any constant; it's sufficient that $|h|<1/|x^{-1}|$.

Comment: Right, makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's because if $a$ is invertible and $\|x\|<\frac1{\|a^{-1}\|}$, then$$(a+x)\left(a^{-1}-(a^{-1})^2x+(a^{-1})^3x^2-(a^{-1})^4x^3+\cdots\right)=1.$$