# Maximal Ideal of a Banach Algebra is closed?

Tags: ideals, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative Banach Algebra with unit and $M$ a maximal Ideal of $A$. Then $M$ is obviously a subspace.
But why must $M$ also be closed?

I don't see in which way a maximal ideal is connected to a closed subspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure $\operatorname{cl}(M)$ of $M$ is also an ideal, as can be checked easily. As $M$ is maximal, we must have either $\operatorname{cl}(M) = M$ or $\operatorname{cl}(M) = A.$ We need show that the later doesn't happen; specifically, $1\not\in \operatorname{cl}(M).$

This follows from the fact that the set of invertible elements in a Banach algebra is open (see [Prove that the set of invertible elements in a Banach algebra is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613552/prove-that-the-set-of-invertible-elements-in-a-banach-algebra-is-open)). Note that for a commutative Banach algebra we have that any element $x$ is not invertible exactly if it is contained in a maximal ideal.

Comment: Potentially $\operatorname{cl}(M)$ could be $A$. To argue that this doesn't happen one needs to prove that any element sufficiently close to $1$ is invertible, and therefore, not in $M$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix this.

Comment: Thank you a lot, both of you :)